# displaying a list on screen with orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using orchard cms 1.6 I have a table in my db 'cars'. I want to display the column 'CarName' from the table, as a list on screen with all the records from the table.

carname1
carname2
carname3

When the user clicks on their link it will bring them to that page.
I know how to do this from the view e.g.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ListofCarNames", new { customer.Id })" title="@T("Cars")">@T("Cars")</a>
```

but I would like to try and create a content type which shows this list.

Content type seems to be all UI related. Im not sure how to take a table and display a column as a list on screen through the content type...any idea on how to do this?

then I can choose to show the content type as a form and the user can view it from the main menu.

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're going straight to the db and not creating an Orchard record class for your part and using a handler class to persist it?

Comment: You do not need, and probably should not use a content type for this. There doesn't seem to be a point. Why would you like to create a content type for this?

Comment: My idea was to create some sort of booking form which orignally shows a list of cars to book. When the user clicks on the car they want it will show a calendar of when the car is next available

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a content type called Car, possibly with a CarPart and a record class CarPartRecord (perhaps refactor your Car class to CarPartRecord to follow Orchard's naming conventions). Make sure CarPartRecord derives from ContentPartRecord.

To render a list of Cars, you could use a Projection that renders a list of cars. A Projection renders content based on a Query, which you configure using the dashboard.

Alternatively, you could create a controller that leverages IContentManager to query all Car content items, and returns a view to render them in a table.

For each Car content item, use Html.ItemDisplayLink to render a link to its details page.